# Unable to write any text in the input field even though this element seems to be in focus

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

The following code is not writing any partial string in the From input field on the website even though this element seems to be an active element.

I spent lot of time trying to debug and make the code work but no success. Can anyone please provide some hint on what is wrong. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from colorama import init, Fore

class BookingTest1():

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    def test1(self):

        baseUrl="https://www.goibibo.com/"

        driver=webdriver.Chrome()

        driver.maximize_window()

        #open airline site

        driver.get(baseUrl)

        driver.implicitly_wait(3)

           

        # Enter origin location.

        partialTextOrigin="New"



        #select flight tab            

        driver. find_element(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='happy-nav']//li//a[@href='/flights/']").click()

        # select input box            

        textElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input")

        # check if input box is active

        if textElement==driver.switch_to.active_element:

            print('element is in focus') 

            textElement.send_keys(partialTextOrigin)           

        else:

            print('element is not in focus')

            print("Focus Event Triggered")

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].focus();", textElement)

            time.sleep(5)

            if textElement==driver.switch_to.active_element:

                print('finally element is in focus')

                print(partialTextOrigin)

                textElement.send_keys(partialTextOrigin)

                time.sleep(5)


#test the code

tst=BookingTest1()

tst.test1()
```

Comment: You don't need to set focus.  The send keys method will do that automatically.  I would use a more targetted selector than "//input".  There are many input tags that are not text input fields.

Comment: ..."active" does not necessarily mean keyboard interactable.

Comment: check the input xpath, i just check it `//input` selects about seven elements, use a more targeted one

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

1. First you need to click on `p` element in the `From` block and only after that when `input` appears there you can insert the text to it.
2. You should use unique locators.  (There more that 10 `input` elements on this page)
3. Using `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits are much better than `implicitly_wait`  in most cases.
4. No need to set timeouts to too short values.
5. No need to use `driver.switch_to.active_element` here.
   The following code works for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "https://www.goibibo.com/"
flights_xpath = "//ul[@class='happy-nav']//li//a[@href='/flights/']"
from_xpath = "//div[./span[contains(.,'From')]]//p[contains(text(),'Enter city')]"
from_input_xpath = "//div[./span[contains(.,'From')]]//input"
partialTextOrigin = "New"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, flights_xpath))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, from_xpath))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, from_input_xpath))).send_keys(partialTextOrigin)
```

`from_xpath` and `from_input_xpath` XPath locators are a little complex.
I was not sure about the class names in that elements block if they are fixed so I based on the texts.
For example `"//div[./span[contains(.,'From')]]//p[contains(text(),'Enter city')]"` means:
Find such `div` that it has a direct `span` child so that `span` contains `From` text content.
From the `div` parent element above find inside it a `p` child that contains  `Enter city` text.
Similarly to the above locator `"//div[./span[contains(.,'From')]]//input"` means: find parent `div` as described before, then find inside it an `input` child element.

The result of the code above is

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you and I appreciate your explaining the issue and solution. The xpaths I had been trying before seemed to have selected the target input box in Chrome dev tools but running the test kept failing. Your xpaths have solved the problem. thanks.

Comment: @kraftwerk  I'm happy my solution helped you. In case it resolved your problem please accept the answer to indicate the question is resolved.